# How to enable BreadCrum in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I have recently installed Eclipse and want to enable as in image in Eclipse under class name as enclosed in image. But I forget how to enable it again. Does anyone know how to enable  quick reference in Eclipse?[image]

Comment: This question is not useful because it could have been solved by googling for "breadcrum eclipse"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the **BreadCrumb** you can get this back using the <kbd>[image: crumb button]</kbd> button

Answer (score 1):

There is a button called "toggle breadcrumbs", it is activated in you image, just after search button.